# When printing, load print.css only and not styles.css

Tags: css

Is there a way to use only print.css and not styles.css when printing? I feel like 90% of my print.css is undoing the styles in styles.css.

Comment: What does your code look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply declare styles.css for the `screen` media type only. If you're including it in a `link` element, add a `media="screen"` attribute to that element.

If you want print.css to override styles.css but still make use of styles from both stylesheets, move your print.css declaration after styles.css instead.

Comment: I totally forgot about media attributes. Thanks so much!